# Setting JRE for project build in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I found several selections in selecting execution environment in Eclipse:
[image]

What does it means all these selection? I see that all of them are related to java version. But what `CDC` and `OSGi` means? And what `(unbound)` means?

Comment: Try Google before SO. [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/tech/index-jsp-139293.html) is the first result when I Google 'CDC', [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077837/java-se/hello--osgi--part-1--bundles-for-beginners.html) is OSGi and [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html) is Java SE. Unbound means Eclipse knows about this JRE, but the path is unknown to it.

Answer (score 1):

The whole list is a Execution environment's available.

Here is the complete list

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments#Standard_Execution_Environments

> EE Name    Description
>   OSGi/Minimum-1.0    OSGi Minimum Execution Environment 1.0 - This is a subset of the J2ME Foundation 1.0 class libraries defined by OSGi to be the base for framework implementations.
>
> OSGi/Minimum-1.1   OSGi Minimum Execution Environment 1.1 - This is a subset of the J2ME Foundation class libraries defined by OSGi to be the base for framework implementations.
>
> CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0 J2ME Foundation 1.0 - With the exception of some MicroEdition IO classes, Foundation 1.0 is a subset of J2SE 1.3.
>
> CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1 J2ME Foundation 1.1 - With the exception of some MicroEdition IO classes, Foundation 1.1 is a subset of J2SE 1.4.

And unbound means, that environment added that environment to your eclipse , and eclipse no more remembered it's path. You need to edit and give the location again.

Answer (score 0):

CDC is Connected Device Configuration, which is a specification for Java ME. Here's a wiki [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_Device_Configuration) for more details.

The OSGi specification describes a modular system and a service platform for the Java programming language that implements a complete and dynamic component model, something that does not exist in standalone Java/VM environments. Here's a wiki [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) if you want to know more about OSGi.

`Unbound` means you previously added that environment to your eclipse, but you need to edit the path and give the location again.

More details as to the execution environments in Eclipse can be found at the Wiki Eclipse page [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments).